# change directory command in my script is not being recognize when i run the script using plink

Tags: linux, windows, bash, shell, batch-file

I'm running a batch file (export.bat) in Windows 7 using `plink` to execute a script in a remote Linux server machine, but I get this error:

```
./test.sh: line 3: back.sh: command not found
```

Batch file:

```
@echo off
cls
plink 1.1.10.11 -l user -pw pass "bash ./test.sh"
```

Script in the remote server:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /path/path/path
script --table filename--filebase /path/path/path/path
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `script` in your remote script is actually `back.sh`, and that it exists in `/path/path/path`.

To execute a script `back.sh` in the directory you `cd` to (i.e. the current directory), use `./back.sh` instead of just `back.sh`.

---

PS: You should generally try to avoid sanitizing input and output of things you post on StackOverflow. It often ends up confusing. For example, you say you get the error `line 3: back.sh: command not found`, but your remote script does not contain the command `back.sh` on line 3 or anywhere.

Instead, invest 15 minutes in making a runnable test case with no sensitive data, that you can actually execute and copy files and errors from verbatim. The [bash tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) has tips for this.